# Android xml drawable color change on selected/focused

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I create a drawable xml file to draw a line using the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="50dp" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Result Image:
[image]

I want to change this image color when it is selected or focused. How can i achieve this? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="line" >
            <solid android:color="@color/newcolor" />
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="50dp" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="line" >
            <solid android:color="@color/newcolor" />
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="50dp" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="50dp" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried this code it doesn't work.

Comment: It will work for clickable buttons images but not in this case. do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: It will work for any view that can be focused or selected and this is what you asked.

Comment: Yes! but it will not work for the drawable shape which is already created using the same xml file! It can work for views background change etc as you said.

Comment: Why did you ask the question if you knew that the answer was not useful to you then?

Comment: *I want to change this image color when it is selected or focused.* you said. How can it be *selected or focused* if it is not a background of a selectable view?

Comment: I also said that _I create a drawable xml file to draw a line_. Anyhow thanks for your time.

Comment: *I create a drawable xml file to draw a line* is what you **did** and *I want to change this image color when it is selected or focused. How can i achieve this?* is what you **asked**!

Comment: yes thats what i asked ! but i also mentioned that i create a line using xml file! Its not a button or view's background! is that so hard?

Comment: Did you mention in your question that *Its not a button or view's background!*? if you did then I would ask: **how can it be focused**?

Comment: THankyou for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple `<item>`s under `<selector>` and specify states as attributes in `<item>` tag.

Here is the syntax

```
<item
    android: state_pressed = ["true" | "false"]
    android: state_focused = ["true" | "false"]
    android: state_hovered = ["true" | "false"]
    android: state_selected = ["true" | "false"]
    android: state_checkable = ["true" | "false"]
    android: state_checked = ["true" | "false"]
    android: state_enabled = ["true" | "false"]
    android: state_activated = ["true" | "false"]
    android: state_window_focused = ["true" | "false"]/>
```